# Latex only letting me put 3 subsection per page, then the numbering starts pilling up unless I add a new page

Tags: sectioning, pdftex, overleaf, white-space

I´m trying to make some specifications fit on one page, but the `\subsection{}` command keeps messing things up unless I create a `\newpage`. I'm using overleaf.

When I do this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%SetFonts
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Precondicion:}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{\textbf{Postcondicion:}}

\newcommand{\BD}{\ Base \ de \ Datos\ }
\newcommand{\nombretabla}{\ nombre\_tabla\ }
\newcommand{\nombrecampo}{\ nombre\_campo\ }
\newcommand{\tipoconsulta}{\ tipo\_consulta\ }

\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{#3}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{format=myformat}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{Registro}
\subsection{}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
  \caption{\textbf{Fields (in r: $registro$, out res : $conj(resgistro)$): } Devuelve los campos de un registro.}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Require
      \Statex $true$
    \Ensure
      \Statex $\hat{res} =_{obs}  campos(r)$
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\subsection{}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
  \caption{\textbf{get (in r : $registro$, in c : $nombre\_campo$) $\to$ res : $valor$: } devuelve el valor del campo 'c' del registro 'r'.}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Require
      \Statex $c \in campos(r)$
    \Ensure
      \Statex $\hat{res} =_{obs}  r[c]$
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\subsection{}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
  \caption{\textbf{add (inout r : $registro$, in c : $nombre\_campo$, in v : $valor$):} devuelve el valor del campo 'c' del registro 'r'.}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Require
      \Statex $r = r_0$
    \Ensure
      \Statex $r = definir(r_0, c, v)$
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\newpage Uncomment to fix but leaves a lot of white space. 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\section{Tabla}

\subsection{}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
  \caption{\textbf{insert (inout T: $Tabla$, in r: $registro$): } Agrega un registro 'r' a una tabla 'T'.}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Require
      \Statex $ fields(r) =_{obs} fields(T) \land T_0 = \hat{T}$
    \Ensure
      \Statex $insertar(T0,\hat{r}) =_{obs} T$
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\subsection{}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
  \caption{\textbf{fields (in T: $Tabla$) $\to$ fields : $conj(nombre\_campo)$: } Dada una tabla 'T', devuelve el nombre de sus campos.}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Require
      \Statex $true$
    \Ensure
      \Statex $fields =_{obs} campos(\hat{T})$
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\subsection{}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
  \caption{\textbf{key (in T: $Tabla$) $\to$ key : $nombre\_campo$: } Devuelve la clave de la tabla.}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Require
      \Statex $true$
    \Ensure
      \Statex $clave(\hat{T}) =_{obs} key$
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

This happens:

[image: The numbers of the subsection Tablas are all pilled up at the bottom of the page]

If I add a new page every three subsections, the issue is solved, but it leaves a lot of white space.

This happens even if I don't start a new section like `Tablas` in this case.

In the original(longer) document the output is the one I've shown in the previous image. But when I compile just this snippet, I get an error regarding  `\maketitle` (no \title given), this does not happen in the original document(it has a cover sleeve where a tittle is defined). And this is the output:

[image: Similar problem as before]

When I comment `\maketitle` the output is this:

[image: Page one looks ok, on page 2 this happens]
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `algorithm` is a float environment, so LaTeX puts its content where it finds enough space and thinks is a good place. If you want to put something in an exact position you shouldn't use a float environment.